# Better question throttling experience on mobile?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I suppose this is an enhancement to the existing feature.

My case:

- had a problem, reported it here;
- had a suggestion right at the same time;
- got throttled with *sorry can post only one thing in 20 minutes*.

Fair enough. Reputation, spammers etc.

Consider the following though:

- on mobile (iOS in my case) I took a long time to craft my question, select title, tags, whatnot.
- I tap "post the question"
- I get "sorry blah blah only every 20 minutes"

The problems I had, as a user/customer:

- that was unexpected;
- the message didn't say how long I have to wait to post something new;
- mobile-specific. In iOS at least the memory management is pretty aggressive. What this means is if I use any other apps while waiting for that 20 minute window the Safari app is gonna get killed, and that in my experience means full reload and loss of the carefully crafted question.

You see? On desktop doesn't matter. On mobile – more so.

My suggestion would be:

- for mobile only (because SE already knows if I'm mobile by looks of it);
- either state at the beginning that I can't post because my quota is exceeded (easily done? Appreciate performance impact);
- or perhaps say how much I have to wait until I can post after I have attempted to do so.

Because otherwise I'm a bit stuck, and I don't know for how long either.

I would suggest stating "you can't post because you need to wait XX minutes" at the beginning of the posting process **on mobile only** would be the preferred solution to me personally.

Summary: provide a better experience on mobile re throttling. Ideally pre- asking question. Otherwise, saying how long the wait is before can post.

(Posting from iPhone apologies for typos and things like that :))

PS: ironically, had lots or trouble posting this, complaining about terms UX all over the place :)

Comment: Not a full solution, but... It seems like perhaps the mobile app should use some sort of persistent storage for drafts until they're submitted. Not just for this - I could easily see connectivity issues making it necessary to hold onto a draft for an indeterminate amount of time as well.